# Fetching data from two different server using TOAD

Tags: sql, toad

I am trying to get data from two different SQL Server using TOAD application.
Here is my query

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN (select count(*) from [BR150\sp_BRVM130].[CCA].dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA)=(select count(*) from [BR150\sp_BRVM124].[HSR].dbo.External_Member_Data)
       THEN 'Row Count For Both Table is equal'
       ELSE 'Row Count For Both Table differs'
       END AS RowCountResult
```

This query runs in sql server perfectly. but when I try to execute this query in TOAD I get following error

```
Could not find server 'BR150\sp_BRVM124' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

I've research over internet and found Cross-server connection is not possible in TOAD. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add linked server with names `BR150\sp_BRVM130`and `BR150\sp_BRVM124`. Look into[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without linked servers using Toad cross-connection sql editor.

https://blog.toadworld.com/performing-cross-connection-queries-with-toad-data-point